# Camera on the forehead activated though a smartwatch

Tags: camera, video-camera, smartwatch

I was wondering whether there are any cameras that can be mounted via a bracket that goes on the forehead and behind the ears.

Such s can camera could be activated via an Android wear watch, and used to take natural photos of people looking into your eyes.

Photos taken of people looking at your face (or at this or that other person's face), are not the same as pictures taken with a person looking at a camera.

Also, when a user pulls out a camera usually the eyes and face of the person being photographed charge.

Therefore, the picture that is wanted is never taken.

The equipment I describe could solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the GoPro have a headband?